# How to force an inheriting class to implement a method in its constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance

The problem that I am having is that I have a bunch of classes (Pages) that inherit from a parent class (BasePage). Any time that I initialize a child class, I also need to run a method called WaitForLoadingToStop(). How do I inherit this method and it's implementation into my child class's constructor?

This is what I need changed because it is duplicated all over the place, therefore, I want this to automatically be inherited and executed when a class is created.

```
        var assPage = new StudentAssesmentPage(Driver);
        assPage.WaitForLoadingToStop();
```

This is a sample child class, I have 10 others that look like this

```
    public class StudentAssesmentPage : BasePage<StudentAssesmentPageObjectRepository>
{
    public StudentAssesmentPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver, new StudentAssesmentPageObjectRepository(driver))
    {}
}
```

Below is my BasePage class

```
    public abstract class BasePage<TObjectRepository> where TObjectRepository : BasePageObjectRepository
{
    protected WebDriverWait Wait { get; }
    protected IWebDriver Driver { get; }
    protected ApplicationUrls ApplicationUrls { get; }
    public IJavaScriptExecutor JavascriptExecutor { get; }
    protected Actions UserInteractions { get; private set; }

    protected By _loadingSpinnerLocator = By.Id("spinner");
    private readonly double LOADING_SPINNER_TIMEOUT = 60;
    private TObjectRepository _objectRepository;

    public BasePage(IWebDriver driver, TObjectRepository repository)
    {
        Driver = driver;
        _objectRepository = repository;
        UserInteractions = new Actions(Driver);
        ApplicationUrls = new ApplicationUrls();
        Wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(GetPageTimeout()));
        JavascriptExecutor = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    }

    internal TObjectRepository ObjectRepository
    {
        get { return _objectRepository; }
    }

    protected bool WaitForLoadingToStop(int secondsToSleep = 5)
    {
        var sleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToSleep);
        Reporter.Debug($"{Helpers.GetCurrentMethodName()}. Going to sleep for:{sleepTime.Seconds}");
        Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
        Reporter.Debug($"Now, going to wait for loading spinner for:{LOADING_SPINNER_TIMEOUT} seconds.");
        var basePageWait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LOADING_SPINNER_TIMEOUT));
        basePageWait.Message =
            $"Waited for {LOADING_SPINNER_TIMEOUT}sec for the spinner. However, it took longer than that for the application to load.";


        return basePageWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("//img[@src='/Content/images/spinner.gif']")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Confused...`WaitForLoadingToStop` is part of the base class but you're calling it directly with no instance in the sample above.  Did you mean `assPage.WaitForLoadingToStop()...` ?

Comment: Oops, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. `WaitForLoadingToStop()` is `protected`, but is apparently called by code outside the declaring class? In any case, it's a bad idea for constructors to be time-consuming. The usual approach to dealing with lengthy initialization is to write a factory method. You can put the wait there, or even better make the whole thing async. As your question is stated so far, it's not clear how it would even work, other than to put that call into the constructor of each child class.

Comment: @PeterDuniho it's not called outside of the calling class. It's called inside of the child classes, although I can see your point of how the example doesn't fully illustrate that. I will update it. But either way it's either called inside of the child classes or by the child classes. Can you further elaborate on this "The usual approach to dealing with lengthy initialization is to write a factory method.". What information do you need from me to help you give me this example? Also, why is it a bad idea for constructors to be time consuming?

Answer (score 1):

Just inherit from a base class implementation `BasePageThatWaitsForLoadingToStop`  that does the work for you in the constructor. The only boilerplate code that is left is passing the constructor argument of a specific implementation (e.g. `StudentAssesmentPage` to this base class)

```
public class StudentAssesmentPage : BasePageThatWaitsForLoadingToStop
{
     public StudentAssesmentPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver, new StudentAssesmentPageObjectRepository(driver)) // this is the only boilerplate code that is left
     {

     }
}

public class BasePageThatWaitsForLoadingToStop : BasePage<StudentAssesmentPageObjectRepository>
{
     public BasePageThatWaitsForLoadingToStop(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver, new StudentAssesmentPageObjectRepository(driver))
     {
         base.WaitForLoadingToStop();
     }
}
```

You can then call it simply as follows and it does the work for you automatically:

```
var assPage = new StudentAssesmentPage(Driver);
```

However, note that from a testing point of view, it is not ideal to do work in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have a question. Why couldn't I just do this same thing in the BasePage constructor as opposed to a new class?

Comment: You can do that as well. Personally, I'd rather prefer to keep things separate (i.e. purely abstract classes/methods and the base implementation of it) by having a base implementation of a purely abstract base class that implements an interface. Using this technique you can create for example base classes that provide a default implementation for some methods (that one can still override if one whishes to) and for other methods you can force the inheriting class to implement a method.

Comment: About your other question in the main comment section: As I said, doing work in the constructor makes it hard and expensive to test the class (see e.g. here at 18:00 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acjvKJiOvXw). Use dependency injection (DI) instead. For example using DI you could have have a Margherita class that sets only its defining properties in the constructor and is then passed on to a Pizza factory, which handles all the complexity. This also allows lazy initialization, i.e. you can take a lot of orders but actually do the work only when and if it is really needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class StudentAssesmentPage : BasePage<StudentAssesmentPageObjectRepository>
{
    public StudentAssesmentPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver, new StudentAssesmentPageObjectRepository(driver))
    {
        base.WaitForLoadingToStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the idea was for the base classes to not all have to manually call the method. Also, code-only answers can usually benefit from some explanation.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewPiliser, I don't want to keep calling this method in every constructor. It violates the DRY priniciple, which is what I am attempting to fix.